# パーティションが見つからない

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04 の入っている HDD が起動しなくなりました。
その原因として、Ubuntu の入っている HDD のパーティションが認識できなくなっていました。

USB メモリから Linux を起動させ  `parted -l` を使った際、次のようなエラーが発生しました

```
エラー：無効な引数です： /dev/sda から読み込み中のシークでエラーが発生しました。
モデル： ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA3 (scsi)
ディスク /dev/sda: 3001GB
セクタサイズ (論理/物理): 512B/4096B
パーティションテーブル: unknown 
ディスクデフラグ：
警告：ドライバは物理ブロックサイズが 2048 バイトであると言っていますが、Linux は 512 バイトだと言っています。
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TestDisk**というパーティション復旧用のユーティリティがあります。
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

確認で使用されたUSB起動のLinuxに含まれている場合もありますし、もし無ければSystemRescueCdなどのLiveCD(USB)がおすすめです。
http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/

コマンドラインから起動するツールですが、基本的には画面の指示に従ってパーティションを検索し、運良く正常なパーティションテーブルが見つかったら実際に書き込む事で復旧の可能性があります。

Answer (score 2):

結論としてはデータを救出したのちにフォーマットし直すことをお勧めします。

> ディスク /dev/sda: 3001GB

従来のPCが採用していたMBR形式のパーティションのセクターサイズは32bit＝4Gセクターが最大値です。１セクターが512バイトの場合、`512B/sector × 4Gsectors = 2TB`までしか管理することができません。質問のハードディスクは3TBですので

1. MBR以外の形式（[GPT](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB)）を使用する
2. １セクターのサイズを512Bより大きくする
3. 前半2TBまでを使用し、後半1TBを捨てる

の選択肢があります。（今起動しようとしているUbuntu 16.04ではなく）ハードディスクのフォーマットに使用したLinuxにも依りますが、一般的には1.のGPT形式が選択されます。しかし

> ドライバは物理ブロックサイズが 2048 バイトであると言っています

この警告メッセージを見る限り、Linuxを起動しようとしたBIOSファームウェアは2.を選択しているように見受けられます。
この場合の不幸は、GPT形式では従来MBRと互換のため先頭セクターが使えない点です。セクターサイズが異なっていればどのセクターも位置が異なってしまうためパーティション情報の読み出しは必ず失敗してしまいます。（MBR形式の場合、先頭セクターを使うためセクターサイズに依らず読み出しに成功します。）

以上を踏まえて、フォーマットを行った際にBIOS / 当該Linuxが認識していたセクターサイズがどうなっていたのか（512B or 2048B）、当該Linuxはどのパーティション形式を選択したのか（MBR or GPT）を確認してください。データが破損しておらずセクターサイズを一致させることができれば、パーティションを認識させることもできるかと思います。

（UEFI対応BIOSならこのようなことにはならないと思うのですが…どこまで話を広げたものか）